# rails 3.2 rails with backbone, can sprockets and requireJs works together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, requirejs, sprockets

In the context of a rails 3.2 rails with backbone, can sprockets and requireJs works together? cannot figure it out myself or find on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use sprockets OR requirejs, but not both. There is a gem for easy use of requirejs in rails (https://github.com/jwhitley/requirejs-rails/).